# Getting a jQuery .click() to activate more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a quote machine that when clicked displays one of the random quotes and it's author found in my arrays. I can get it to display a random quote once, but clicking the button again does nothing.

```js
//VARIABLES
///////////////
var quotes = [
  ["Quote 1", "Author 1"],
  ["Quote 2", "Author 2"],
  ["Quote 3", "Author 3"],
  ["Quote 4", "Author 4"]
];

var randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];


//FUNCTIONS
///////////////
function quoteGeneration() {
  $(".quotes").replaceWith(randomQuote);
};


//QUOTE BUTTON
/////////////////
$(".quote-button").click(function() {
  quoteGeneration();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote-box">
  <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
  <p class="quotes">This is where the quotes go.</p>
  <span class="quote-authors">Quote author</span>

  <div class="social-media">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
  </div>

  <button class="quote-button">New Quote</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues. The first is because you remove the `.quotes` element from the DOM on the first click. Use `text()` instead of `replaceWith()`:

```
$(".quotes").text(randomQuote);
```

The second is that your logic is flawed as you only pick a quote randomly once on load of the page. That should be done within the click handler. Try this:

```js
var quotes = [
  ["Quote 1", "Author 1"],
  ["Quote 2", "Author 2"],
  ["Quote 3", "Author 3"],
  ["Quote 4", "Author 4"]
];

$(".quote-button").click(function() {
  var randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  $(".quotes").text(randomQuote);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote-box">
  <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
  <p class="quotes">This is where the quotes go.</p>
  <span class="quote-authors">Quote author</span>

  <div class="social-media">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
  </div>

  <button class="quote-button">New Quote</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is not the function, it is that the text is being replaces with the same quote every time. `randomQuote` is being set once and never again, so the change is happening but because nothing changes you wont see anything happening

Comment: The problem is also the function - fixing the random selection alone will produce the same behaviour as the `.quotes` element is removed by `replaceWith()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the click. Your problem is you generate the random number once and read the quotes once.

Move the random number/quote selection inside of the method. Also you are replacing the element, not the text inside.

```js
//VARIABLES
///////////////
var quotes = [["Quote 1", "Author 1"], ["Quote 2", "Author 2"], ["Quote 3", "Author 3"], ["Quote 4", "Author 4"]];



//FUNCTIONS
///////////////
function quoteGeneration() {
   var randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length )];
   $(".quotes").text(randomQuote);
};


//QUOTE BUTTON
/////////////////
$(".quote-button").click( function() {
   quoteGeneration();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote-box">
  <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
  <p class="quotes">This is where the quotes go.</p>
  <span class="quote-authors">Quote author</span>

  <div class="social-media">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
  </div>

  <button class="quote-button">New Quote</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your variable `randomQuote` inside a function so that it gets the random quote everytime the click event is called As of now `randomQuote` is being set only one time on inital load hence the value doesnot chnage and use `html` instead of `replaceWith()`

```js
//VARIABLES
///////////////
var quotes = [["Quote 1", "Author 1"], ["Quote 2", "Author 2"], ["Quote 3", "Author 3"], ["Quote 4", "Author 4"]];

//FUNCTIONS
///////////////
function quoteGeneration() {
   var randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length )];
   $(".quotes").html(randomQuote);
};

//QUOTE BUTTON
/////////////////
$(".quote-button").click( function() {
   quoteGeneration();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote-box">
  <h1>Random Quote Generator</h1>
  <p class="quotes">This is where the quotes go.</p>
  <span class="quote-authors">Quote author</span>

  <div class="social-media">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
  </div>

  <button class="quote-button">New Quote</button>
</div>
```